# How do I add these tiny dots at the end of line plots in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I am trying to add these tiny bubbles at the end of line plots. How to do that in matplotlib?

[image]

Comment: There are already end points on the lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try with [`plt.plot.markevery`](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/markevery_demo.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
delta = 0.11
x = np.linspace(0, 10 - 2 * delta, 200) + delta
y = np.sin(x) + 1.0 + delta


plt.plot(x,y,'o',ls='-', ms=8,markevery=[-1])
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this (on top of the solution present by @MrNobody33) is to superimpose line graphs and scatter plots. That way, if you have specific values you want to showcase, you can add them to the scatter plots.

**Code Example**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Show the Lines
plt.plot([0, 10], [0, 10], color='b')
plt.plot([2, 7], [0, 3], color='r')

# Show the endpoints using Scatter plots
plt.scatter([10], [10], color='b')
plt.scatter([7], [3], color='r')

# show the graph
plt.show()
```

[image]